# Android Create View Crash

Tags: java, android, visual-studio

I'm trying to add Layout with this code:

```
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mYouTubePlayerLayout = (ConstraintLayoutKeyDispatchWrapper) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.background_player_layout, null, false);
    mYouTubePlayerLayout.setOnDispatchKeyEventListener(this);
    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) activity.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    createWindowParams(true);
    mWindowManager.addView(mYouTubePlayerLayout, mWindowParams);
```

I understand that I need to get permissions from the user for 23 version and above, so I'm asking the user for the permission with this code:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && !Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            isAppPlayStorePermission = true;

            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);

            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            dialog.setTitle(R.string.dialog_need_playstore_permissions_title);
            dialog.setMessage(R.string.dialog_need_playstore_permissions_description);

            dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_exit, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    AndroidUtils.exitApp(activity);
                }
            });

            dialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.button_settings, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                }
            });

            dialog.show();

        }
```

but now I'm getting a crash from `Fabric`:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to create service ***: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@c7450fc -- permission denied for this window type
```

The crash is only for users with Android OS of 7 and below.
Any idea what is the problem?